# Why is React Native Native Event pageX and pageY appearing inaccurate?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a simple drag and drop ReactNative component in my application where the component can be dragged from one location to another. I'm trying to figure out why my component is not responding correctly to changes in its position.

Even after setting the X and Y location to be pageX and pageY, it shifts downward first and slightly to the right. What is causing this slight change to happen?

Here's the code:

```js
class Item extends React.Component
{
   ...

    pressItem = (evt) => {
    this.setState({shouldRotate: true});

    if (evt.nativeEvent) {

        let newX = evt.nativeEvent.pageX;
        let newY = evt.nativeEvent.pageY;
        this.state.x = newX;
        this.state.y = newY;



    }

};
 ...

    render()
    {

        return (
            <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
                  onResponderRelease={this.releaseItem}
                  onResponderMove={this.pressItem}
                  style={[
                      styles.item,
                      {top: this.state.y,position: 'absolute',
                          left: this.state.x,
                          }]}>
            <Animated.Image source={this.props.imageURL}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            style={{width: "100%", height: "100%",
                                transform: [{rotate: this.state.spin}]}}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are not setting the state correctly. You have to change it by calling `this.setState()`

Comment: You're right but I changed it and it still has the same effect.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?